# What's a better way of saying "rarely used"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, vocabulary

I'm writing an article about using rarely used English words and how to learn and use them. As an example I'd like to find an alternate way of saying "rarely used" I believe there should be one word for this in the English language.

Comment: I think dictionaries just use the tag *rare* for words with that usage level.

Comment: One word? Just one?  [Start here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/rare) and recurse until done.

Comment: Then [use *spanonymic* — or any other of these](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/164935/2085) by appending *‑ic* to each. But next to nobody will know what you are saying.

Comment: '*[Seldom](http://gog.is/define+seldom)* used.'

Answer (score 0):

Use *obscure* or *esoteric*; neither exactly means *rare*, but both fit your context.

Comment: thanks, I like "esoteric". Now I realize that in this particular context I want to use a word like "esoteric" particularly because it's esoteric to many people.